# JavaScript page jump when updating element using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a page which FITS vertically into the windo. When user clicks on the link, I get another page via ajax and plug it into the required element.
Everything works, But when user clicks on another link, page jumps up and it is annoying me.
I have tried using

```
<a href="#" onClick="showRoom('five');return false;" class="highlight">
//and
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="showRoom('five');return false;" class="highlight">
```

and it did not work in both IE and Firefox - it continues to jump.

Is there any good working trick that could help?

I THINK that it has to do something with the  renew. When I click the link - first, the LOADING ICON is showing. Only then, when reports table is available, it loads into the  instead of icon. Therefore browser adds vscrolling bars when information is shown, but goes away in between reports switches and being replaced by small LOADING icon.

I think that I need to capture the scrollbar location when I click on the update link, then, after ajax updates the page, I need to call in another function that would scroll back to previous scrollbar location

This is how I "fixed" the problem, until real solution is discovered:

```
document.getElementById(showCoursesArea).innerHTML= '<center><img src=\"images/working.gif\"><h1><br><h1><br><h1><br><h1><br><h1><br><h1><br></center>';
```

pretty much it kepps my page LONG; therefore ajax updates are fitting right in.

Comment: Can you post it into a jsFiddle?

Comment: What do you mean by "jumps up"? Be more specific, please

Comment: Do you see the vscrollbar on the right? It disappears for a short wile during the update - because the report table goes away and I have the LOADING ICON instead. Then, Ajax pulls the new table from the database and fills in my <div>- scrollbar appear again, but page does not gets back to report

Comment: so far, how I "fixed" the problem: I added bunch of spaces after the LOADING icon - so browser could keep original some page height. `document.getElementById(showCoursesArea).innerHTML= '<center><img src=\"images/working.gif\"><h1><br><h1><br><h1><br><h1><br><h1><br><h1><br></center>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'#' will take the user back to the top of the page, so I usually go with void(0). or if as you are saying second option is also not working than remove href and try out

or just try out

```
<a href="javascript:myJsFunc()">Link Text</a>
```

or

```
<a onclick="javascript:myJsFunc()">Link Text</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#0" onclick="myJsFunc()">Link Text</a>
```

as id "0" will never be present on a page so that nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a link with `href="#"` it is actually linking to the top of the document. You can actually just remove the `href` attribute completely.

Comment: <span onClick="showRoom('five');" class="highlight">Room 5</span>

Comment: Or add an anchor to the new page. that way it might scroll down a bit